# How to retrieve data from XML with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, parsing, dom

I need to get all the data contained in this file XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Tags>
      <Tag>
        <Nome>#SaintDenis</Nome>
        <Classe>21</Classe>
     </Tag>
    ....
    </Tags>
```

in order to create an array arr like this

```
    arr [[SaintDenis, 21]......]
```

how can i parse the structure of the xml file in javascript...
thank you in advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $.get('myData.xml', function(d){
        $('body').append('<h1> Recommended Web Development Books </h1>');
        $('body').append('<dl />');

        $(d).find('book').each(function(){

            var $book = $(this); 
            var title = $book.attr("title");
            var description = $book.find('description').text();
            var imageurl = $book.attr('imageurl');

            var html = '<dt> <img class="bookImage" alt="" src="' + imageurl + '" /> </dt>';
            html += '<dd> <span class="loadingPic" alt="Loading" />';
            html += '<p class="title">' + title + '</p>';
            html += '<p> ' + description + '</p>' ;
            html += '</dd>';

            $('dl').append($(html));

            $('.loadingPic').fadeOut(1400);
        });
    });
});
```

See http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-jquery-to-retrieve-data-from-an-xml-file--net-390 for more information

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion.

```
function iterate (node) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var child = node.childNodes[i];
      iterate(child);
      //gather info here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is your input, so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Tags>
      <Tag>
        <Nome>#SaintDenis</Nome>
        <Classe>21</Classe>
     </Tag>
    ....
    </Tags>
```

The best thing is do some stuff like this:

```
function getValues ( XMLnode ) {
    var Values = [];
    var childs = XMLnode.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
      var array_temp = [];
      if(childs[i].nodeName == 'Tag'){    // I think each tag have names and classe
         var childsTag = childs[i].childNodes;
         var array_temp_2 = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
             array_temp_2.push( childs[i].value ) ; // here you can use 'value'
                                                    // use your own tag('name' or whatever)
         }
         array_temp.push(array_temp_2);
      } 
       Values.push( array_temp );
    }
    return Values;
}
```

And thats all:

```
var valuesXML = [];
valuesXML = getValues( XMLnode ) ;
```